# LINQ Query Syntax for Self Join

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Table Jobs is the primary file record with the JobId.

Table PostThr records the scheduling of when the jobs begin and end. There are 5 fields: ID, FK, ThrDate(DateTime), ThrTime(TimeSpan), and ThrText(string). There is one entry for a job start and another for the job end. The jobs do not last for more than one date, ie overnight.

The goal is to show how many jobs are active at the same time, rather within the same hour block, using the records in PostThr. I feel like this is a LINQ query, some sort of join, and I'm not sure of the syntax.

```
DateTime givenDate = DateTime.Parse("7/2/22");
DateTime givenTime = TimeSpan.Parse("9:00");

int y = _context.PostThrs.Where(m =>
            m.ThrDate == dateZero &&
            ((
            m.ThrText == "CONFIRM START-" &&
            m.ThrTime >= myTime
            ) && (
            m.ThrText == "CONFIRM END-" &&
            m.ThrTime <= myTime
            ))

        ).Count();
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you don't have any column linking the starting and stopping processes.  That would make your life a lot easier because anything that starts and stops during the interval runs the risk of being counted twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try to match the date only in the date condition because when we are usually comparing date it also compares the time as well. Hope you find this helpful